# Using pac file as proxy and requests in Python

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I'm interested to know how I can use provided PAC file to access a website. I'd like to use the data in the file as a proxy input for a get request.

I came across some similar questions, but none of them helped me solve my problem. Anyway, I'll keep them below as a reference:

- [Parse PAC files in Python without using C modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911029/parse-pac-files-in-python-without-using-c-modules)
- [How to use Proxy PAC file for python urllib or request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528812/how-to-use-proxy-pac-file-for-python-urllib-or-request)
- [Proxy settings for Python requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815565/proxy-settings-for-python-requests-module)
- [Proxies with Python 'Requests' module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)
- [How to tell R to use proxy auto config script (PAC) in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538695/how-to-tell-r-to-use-proxy-auto-config-script-pac-in-windows)
- [How to find proxy server and password from .pac file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508397/how-to-find-proxy-server-and-password-from-pac-file)

The minimal example here is:

```py
import requests

pac_url = "https://www.tau.ac.il/remote.pac"
website_url = "https://www.jstor.org/stable/i27924418"
user_name = "user"
password = "pass"

response = requests.get(website_url)
print(response) # <Response [420]>
```

Obviously, I need to do something in order to make use of the PAC file. So I experiment with a few options:

### 1 - Define proxy in Windows setting

[image: windows proxy definition]

I changed the default proxy setting in Windows to support that PAC and then tried the following code (with `request.getproxies()` parameter):

```
import requests
from urllib import request
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

pac_url = "https://www.tau.ac.il/remote.pac"
website_url = "https://www.jstor.org/stable/i27924418"
user_name = "user"
password = "pass"

response = requests.get(website_url, proxies=request.getproxies(), auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user_name , password))
print(response) # <Response [420]>
```

### 2 - Proxy setting in the code

I manually extracted the host name from the pac file and used it:

```py
import requests

pac_url = "https://www.tau.ac.il/remote.pac"
website_url = "https://www.jstor.org/stable/i27924418"
user_name = "user"
password = "pass"

proxies = {
    "http": "http://user:pass@proxy.tau.ac.il:8080/"
}
response = requests.get(website_url, proxies=proxies)
print(response) #<Response [420]>
```

### 3 - Using PyPac

I attempted to follow PyPac's installation instructions, but after the next line:

```
pip install pypac
```

I received that error

```
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-
tools/
```

I installed Visual Studio build tools 2019, but it did not resolve the issue. The same message was received again.

---

**So I'm stuck at those three dierctions, wondering what I can do. I would appreciate any assistance.**

Comment: I'm a bit late there ; to my knowledge, pypac is indeed the solution and there are wheels available for windows on pypi. I seem to remember though that depending on your python version, you might have trouble with some packages on windows (for instance, dukpy) ; in that case, you can find wheels on [this website](http://eturnbull.ca/pythonlibs/).